# Copy Data from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two tables with different number of rows and I wish to copy a column of data and insert it to the second table. How could I do that? I know how to insert the data with two tables with the same number of columns but what I should of in my situation?

```
TABLE A
ID | Exp | T/F | RATE |
======================
1  |  11 |  T  |  0.45|
-----------------------
:      :    :    

Table B
ID |  Year | Exp | Sex | V | VI | VII|
======================================
1  |  2011 |  11 |  M  | x | x  | c  |
--------------------------------------
:     :       :      :    :   :    :
```

In the example, I wish to insert [Rate] from table A to table B.
What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: From preponderance of evidence, I am guessing that you are really using SQL Server.  Fix the tags if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `update` operation.

First, though, if the column is not present, you need to add it:

```
alter table b add rate decimal(4, 2); -- or whatever the appropriate type is
```

Then you can update it.  Assuming the `id` columns are the same:

```
update b
    set rate = a.rate
    from b join
         a
         on b.id = a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--In which column you want to insert rate in second table
--in my guess try this it might help you

    Insert into [TABLE A] (--the column names where you want to insert)
    Select (--the column what you want to select) From [TABLE B] ;

    --Example
    Insert into [Table A] (ID,Exp)
    Select (Id,Exp) From [Table B]
```